# SAS PROC Document - Giving Requested function is not supported when creating HTML page

Tags: sas

Created test using PROC DOCUMENT as below:

```
ods listing ;
ods document name=test(write);
proc report data=sashelp.prdsal3 contents=' Country wise Product and Actual SALE';  
columns country product actual ; 
define country / display;
define product / display ;
run;

ods proctitle=on;
title 'This is a simple PROC TABULATE procedure'; 
proc tabulate data=sashelp.prdsal3 ;
class country product  ; 
var actual;
table country * product , actual / contents='SALE actuals';
run;
ods document close;

ods listing; 
proc document name=test;
list / levels=all;
run;
ods listing close;

Here is the listing: 
ods listing; 
proc document name=test;
list / levels=all;
run;
ods listing close;


Listing of: \Work.Test\
Order by: Insertion
Number of levels: All
```

### Obs           Type

1              Dir
   2 \Report#1    Dir
   3 \Report#1Report#\Report#1     Table
   4              Dir
   5 \Tabulate#1Report#1      Dir
   6 \Tabulate#1\Report#1Table#1   Table

Getting error with this code:

```
ods html file='c:\documents and settings\ANA\Output\ODS_contents_TEST.html';
proc document name=test;
 replay ;
run;
ods html close;

NOTE: PROCEDURE DOCUMENT used (Total process time):
      real time           24.64 seconds
      cpu time            0.06 seconds


432  proc document name=test;
433   replay ;
434  run;

ERROR: Requested function is not supported.
435  ods html close;
NOTE: Remote submit to WINDOWS complete.
```

What could be the problem

Comment: That works for me on 9.4.  You might check into whether it's specific to your version; looking at hotfixes, there are some related to that kind of error (though not obviously this specific one).  Perhaps start a TS track with SAS Support.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs Joe.  I am using 9.2 version. I saw in one place that there is less support on ODS DOCUMENT and PROC DOCUMENT for a few procedures like PROC TABULATE, but lesser limitations for PROC PRINT. But for me PROC PRINT is also not working. Unfortunately I cant raise a ticket for the Enclave server that I am working on :(